# Sending emails in webmatrix - Max numbers of destinataries

Tags: email, razor, webmatrix

So i got an application builded in webmatrix, and i build a function to send email. Everything works great if i put like 5 or 6 destinataries, however sometimes i need to send to 100+ destinataries and it doesn´t work.

Is there a max number of destinataries?

Updated

```
 try
                 {
                    // Initialize WebMail helper
                    WebMail.SmtpServer = "mysmtpserver";
                    WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
                    WebMail.UserName = "myuser";
                    WebMail.Password = "mypass";
                    WebMail.From = "myemail";

                    // Enviar email
                    WebMail.Send(to: "myemail",
                        bcc:sendMail,
                        subject: "Indisponibilidades - " + numeroTicket,
                        body: ocorrencia + " - " + numeroTicket + "<br>"
                        + "Inicio: " + dataInicio + " " + horaInicio + "<br>"
                    );
                }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        errorMessage = ex.Message;
                    }
```

One more thing i'm using a webservice to send SMS at the same time but there is no problem with the SMS. And if i send the email do 5 or 6 people (like i said before) it sends the sms and the email.

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @MikeBrind, I think he means to say "Emails are not being sent".

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Obviously, but some more detail on the what happens - error message, some code perhaps - would help.

Comment: @MikeBrind, Yes I was expecting that too. But I am assuming the port or the connection is closed, because why would ASP.NET close the connection to the service.

Comment: Hi Mike and Afzal i've updated the question with some code.

Comment: I think the `bcc` object is the culprit, you might be passing on the huge list of recipients to the `bcc` and the service provider is disconnecting after a few `bcc` recipients. Maybe there limit for the `bcc` is only 5-6 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is an ASP.NET WebMail related issue, I think your service provider is trying to disconnect you from their service for such a bulk data. Somehow, `to: ""` parameter is meant for just one value.

You must use a `foreach` loop to loop through many email recipients. Something like this

```
var customers = "the value of them here"; // must be array
foreach (var customer in customers) {
   WebMail.Send(to: customer.Email,
                subject: "your-subject", 
                body: "Email body here!");
}
```

This would be enough for this purpose, this way you can even close the thread for a few moments and wait for the current email to be sent. Some email service providers are providing service to other members too. So they close the connection too soon. ASP.NET won't close the connection itself only because you had a huge list of recipients.

#### Edit

As I have already mentioned in the answer, there is no such issue relating ASP.NET to be the culprit for disconnecting the email sending process. This might be something related to the email service provider of yours. You should post this at their forum and ask them "what should I do if I have to send more than 10 emails at once".

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806037/Sending-emails-easily-using-ASP-NET-helpers

Do read the above article, I have tried to explain the ASP.NET WebMail helper there. The code you're sharing here, has no such issue that might cut down the network connection if the emails exceed 10 in number.

#### Issue (might be this one)

One more time I am asking you to not include `bcc` and use a simple loop, for or foreach loop to send the email to every recipient. Maybe your service provider doesn't allow more than 5 bcc in the email.

Use a simple foreach loop like I have gave in the code above, and send email to each of the users. Most of the email providers don't allow many `bcc` recipients.

Comment: Ok i understand your point, but just one more thing. Right now we are sending those emails through outlook with that  "list" on bcc, and there is no problem with that, the emails are sent. So i think that our service provider allows more than 5 bcc.

Comment: @Nibbler Yes, if OutLook can send more than 5bcc then yes, **Outlook** allows _more than 5 bcc_. You can try using OutLook if it fits your needs. :)

Comment: yeap but that is a workaround, i will try your solution. Thanks a lot for you help once again.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using an email delivery service like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com).

They have a [C# wrapper library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp) that has all the instructions you'll need to get it installed and running.  I've used it with WebMatrix so can vouch it'll work.

To send up to [25K free emails a month](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/gallery/store/sendgrid/sendgrid-azure-b/) sign up for windows azure and add SendGrid as a service. You'll then get an API key you can use in any of your apps.